# How to access Google bucket files using python tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-storage

If I want to access Google bucket files using python during training job on Google Machine Learning engine (not locally). What is the correct approach from the following choices (if any)?

- use the built in open(filePath) python function where filePath is
  valid google bucket path e.i. 'gs://bucket/folder/file.ext'
- use the Python Client for Google Cloud Storage
  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-cloud-storage

the first choice is clearly much easier, if it is valid, does it requires special set up such as: setting specific bucket permissions or default storage class.

best regards.

Comment: By "training," are you talking about training ML models? Are you doing this using Google Cloud ML Engine, with TensorFlow, or some other system?

Comment: yes I'm using tensorflow  to train faster CNN model on Google ML engine @BrandonYarbrough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither this or this. One should use the tensorflow Gfile module as follow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.gfile.GFile("gs://bucket/file", "r") as f:
        content = f.read()
```